# Jquery find in Array and return members

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have the following Json Data pushing to an array, i would like find an id value and return id,name,lastname

```
searchSearch.push({
                id: layer.feature.properties.ID,
                name: layer.feature.properties.Name
                lastname: layer.feature.properties.LastName
            });
```

I have found out how to get the match in the array using

```
var exist=$.grep(searchSearch, function(obj) { return obj.id === this.id;});
```

How do i return the id, name, lastname to the console.log for example?

Answer (score 0):

[**`$.grep`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) returns an array of elements for which the callback returns `true`. Assuming there is only one element with such an ID, simply access the properties of the first element. For example:

```
console.log(exist[0].name);
console.log(exist[0].lastname);
```

---

Note: Your test (`obj.id === this.id`) is incorrect. `this` refers to `window`. Unless you have a global variable `id`, this won't work. *If* you have a global variable `id`, you should not access it like this.